# Xcode put NSObject's isProxy method as my custom class’s property

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

I have a custom class which has a NSNumber property :isProxy , and when I used this property in swift:

```
  if (userInfoModel.isProxy.boolValue){...}
```

Xcode recognize the isProxy property as NSObject's isProxy method , and give me an error:

```
 Method 'isProxy' was used as a property; add () to call it
```

i can't mapping the isProxy to another name , because this property has already used in many place in my project ,so I can't change its name.

So is there an way to fix this bug?

Comment: Try making this a `computed` property?

Comment: Instead of editing your question with a note about your solution, either post an actual answer if you believe it will help others or delete your question if you don't.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't received any error by my code from your's:

```
@interface VerticallyAlignedLabel : UILabel {
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *isProxy;

@end

VerticallyAlignedLabel *label = [[VerticallyAlignedLabel alloc] init];
int isProxyValue = label.isProxy.intValue;
NSLog(@"isProxyValue:%d",isProxyValue);
```

Can you show me your class 'get' and 'set' methods?

Comment: The question is about Swift code, not Objective-C code.

Comment: thank you ， I had solve it by adding a new property and return self.isProxy